# show different label and values for columns in cognos report studio

Tags: report, cognos, cognos-10, drilldown

I have a column "full name" in a list and I want to configure drill down for it so that when I click on a particular user's full name, it displays all the bio data of that user from another table.
My requirement is that at the front end, it should show the full names of the users, but when I click on the user's name, it should pass E-mail address of the user for the drill down.

Please need help for doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using a list object. the instructions for a crosstab would be slightly different:

1. Add the item you want to pass to the drill-through target to your query
2. In the report page, select the list
3. Click on the ellipses (...) in the 'Properties' property of the list object
4. Check the box next to the data item that you added to the query in step 1 and click 'OK'
5. When you define the drill-through parameters, select 'Pass the data item value' for the method and the data item added to the query in step 1 as the Value.